# Push a view controller from table embedded in a UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, view, controller, pushviewcontroller

The structure for my view is as follows. I display the cover of each chapter of a catalogue in the header view of a UITableView, and display the subsections of each chapter in the corresponding table view.I have these all embedded in a paging UIScrollView which is the rootViewController for a navigation controller. The stack is:

```
UINavigationController (controlled by CatMainViewController [UIViewController])
    UIScrollView       (controlled by CatMainViewController [UIViewController])
        UITableView    (controlled by SectionViewController [UITableViewController])
```

I would like to know how I can communicate with the CatMainViewController from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method on my SectionViewController to tell the navigation controller to push a view controller which loads a document.

I have tried something like:

```
#import "CatMainViewController.m"
[CatMainViewController.self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

But obviously this hasn't worked out so well. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference of the `CatMainViewController` instance to the `SectionViewController` instance, for example:

```
/* SectionViewController.h */
@class CatMainViewController;

@interface SectionViewController

// ... some properties/methods
@property (nonatomic, assign) CatMainViewController *catMainVC;
// ... more properties/methods

@end

/* SectionViewController.m */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ... some code
    [self.catMainVC.navigationController pushViewController:someVC animated:YES];
}

/* CatMainViewController.m */
#import "SectionViewController.h"

// when creating the SectionViewController
SectionViewController *sectionViewController = ...;
sectionViewController.catMainVC = self;
```

This is similar to the delegate/`@protocol` scheme that Apple uses.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. I tried something along these lines but couldn't connect all the dots. I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: when I try to type [self.catMainVC.navigationController...... ] it doesn't work for me. Is there a line missing here?

Comment: You just need to make sure the `@property ... catMainVC` is in `SectionViewController.h`, along with `@synthesize catMainVC;` in `SectionViewController.m`.